# Hook after image is uploaded and image sizes generated

Tags: hooks, actions, images

I'd like to compress images once they're uploaded to media library. Is there any hook that fires once the image is uploaded and the image sizes generated?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Is there any hook that fires once the image is uploaded and the image sizes generated?

[`wp_handle_upload`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_handle_upload/) fires after the image is uploaded. After the follow-up question, I discovered that images would not be sized at this point.

```
add_filter( 'wp_handle_upload' 'wpse_256351_upload', 10, 2 );
function wpse_256351_upload( $upload, $context ) {
  //* Do something interesting
  return $upload;
}
```

Added:

Images are resized on [line 135](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.7/src/wp-admin/includes/image.php#L135) of image.php. There are no hooks in method to resize the images.

At the end of the wp_generate_attachment_metadata() function, [`wp_generate_attachment_metadata`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_generate_attachment_metadata/) fires. This is after the image sizes are generated.

[`wp_read_image_metadata`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_read_image_metadata/) is another option. It fires before `wp_generate_attachment_metadata` but after image sizes are generated.

Comment: Hmm, are the image sizes already generated at this time?

Comment: @user1049961 You're right. The image sizes would not be generated when wp_handle_upload fires. Not sure what I was thinking. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `wp_generate_attachment_metadata` filter for this, it's fired in the [wp_generate_attachment_metadata](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_generate_attachment_metadata/) function.